# How to select data from MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

The following operation returns all the documents from the collection `products` where `qty` is greater than `25`:

```
db.products.find( { qty: { $gt: 25 } } )
```

Instead of `qty` I have a string `info` (in xml format).

How to return all documents from the collection `products` where `info` contains some tag?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a document you want to remove?

Comment: I don't want to remove a document, I want to remove a value from tag, tag  in the string, string in the document, document in the `products` collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [`forEach` loop in Mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) for this, and update each record individually.

This will replace `<password>asdfghj</password>` in the `info` XML to `<password></password>` for each record that has a `<password>` entry in the `info` field (assuming the password value doesn't have a `<` in it)

```
db.getCollection('products').find({info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}}).forEach(
    function(document) {
        var info = document.info;
        document.info = info.replace(/<(.*?password)>([^<]+)<\/(.*?password)>/gmi, "<$1></$3>");
        db.products.save(document);
    }
);
```

Comment: Instead of `qty` I have a string `info` (in xml format). So you don't need to do `find({qty:{$gt:25}})`

Comment: Ah okay, I've changed the find criteria to match [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36065090/3000179) - my confusion

Comment: Can you please improve your algorithm, because I want to replace for each record that CONTAINS  `<password>` entry in the `info` field. (not exactly `password`)?

Comment: Do we need to change `find({info:{$regex: /<password>/}})` because of `contains` ?

Comment: Oh yes, check the edit. This should be what you're looking for `find({info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}})`

Comment: `db.getCollection('products').find({info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}})` Fetched 0 record(s). 

Looks like this algorithm don't work(

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? It works for me: https://i.gyazo.com/8dcd8d188ced09584e13993a11cb5242.gif

Comment: I've tested the query in a MongoDB 3 and 2.6 instance, both bringing back results... `:/`

Comment: Do your algorithm work if you set `pass` instead of `password` in `find({info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}})` ?

Comment: It does, yes. Both `{info:{$regex: /<.*?pass.*?>/i}}` `{info:{$regex: /<.*?password>/i}}` on 2.6

Comment: Ooooh, so I need to end with `.*?`  !  Previously you just started with `.*?` in `/<.*?password>/i`

Comment: I'm unsure if you're searching for `...pass>` or `...password>` so I put both, aha!

Comment: I think its more general solution `{info:{$regex: /<.*?password.*?>/i}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to search the `info` string

`db.products.find({info:{$regex: /<password>/}})`

Comment: And how to delete values of all of this tags?

Comment: As I mention, I want to `have tags which name CONTAIN password` , not exactly `password`